# Approximating $f(1)$ given $f(0)=2$ and $\frac{1}{2}x^2≤f'(x)≤x^2$?

Tags: calculus, approximation

This is an exercise using the mean value theorem:

Approximate $f(1)$ given $f(0)=2$ and $\frac{1}{2}x^2≤f'(x)≤x^2$ for $x≥0$.

I've found (using MVT):

$$\frac{1}{2}x^2+2≤f(1)≤x^2+2$$

and I can constrain this to

$$2≤f(1)≤x^2+2$$ by noting that $x≥0$ by assumption.

But what should I do with the upper bound?

Comment: You are applying the MVT on the interval  $[0,1]$, so you can upper bound it by taking  $x^2+2 \leq 1+2=3$

Comment: @Nizar Well the MVT says that theres a $c \in ]0,1[$ s.t. $f'(c)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}$, but it says it for $c$ and $f'(c)$ and not $x$ and $f(x)$?

Comment: Isn't you inequality valid for every $x$ ? Why not applying it to $c$ !

Comment: I don't exactly get what you are saying, however note that $f'(x) \geq  0.5 x^2 \geq 0 $ so $f$ is increasing!

Answer (score 3):

Note that in mean value theorem, $$\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=f'(x)$$
where $\large \color{red}{x \in (0,1)}$.

So we can re-state this as $$\frac{1}{2}x^2 \leq \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0} \leq x^2$$ where $\large \color{red}{x \in (0,1)}$

Or better, $$\frac{1}{2}x^2+f(0) \leq f(1) \leq x^2+f(0)$$   where $\large \color{red}{x \in (0,1)}$

Hence,
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot (1)^2+f(0) \leq f(1) \leq 1^2+f(0)$$ Or,

> $$\frac{5}{2} \leq f(1) \leq 3$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why did you pick $x=1$ for the lower bound, second last inequalities?

Comment: @mavavilj Well, you can choose any other $x$ in the interval $(0,1)$ but all those would give intervals of $f(1)$ as subsets of this interval. Check it using $x=0$ or $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Of course I'm interested in finding the best approximation.

Comment: @mavavilj Well, you are using mean value theorem, so it has its limit on the accuracy of results.

Comment: Selecting $x=0$ would give $2≤f(1)≤2$, but how does one know whether that's more accurate than $3/2≤f(1)≤3$?

Comment: @mavavilj That's the limitation of this theorem. You cannot comment on which is more accurate. So you have to go with what is surely true.

Comment: @mavavilj $f(1)$ can be $2$ but it can be other things too. You just cannot comment on that when you are using this inequality.

Comment: Shouldn't one pick the broadest bounds then?

Comment: Yes, I have picked the broadest bounds only. And thanks for correcting. Updated the answer and corrected the typo.

Comment: You get a broader lower bound 2 by letting $x=0$

Comment: By broader, I mean a longer interval.

Answer (score 3):

By the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)
$$
f(1)-f(0)=\int_0^1f'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac16\le f(1)-2\le\frac13
$$
That is,
$$
\frac{13}6\le f(1)\le\frac73
$$
which is a bit tighter than the mean value theorem gives, if that matters.

Comment: Clearly the best answer, it uses all the information provided for all values of $x$ over $[0,1]$, not just at some random point.

Comment: I wanted to use the MVT though, not fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @mavavilj: that is why I said, "if that matters". :-) You are free to accept the answer that uses the Mean Value Theorem (I have upvoted it because it does use MVT; however, I see nothing wrong in presenting an alternate approach).